# how to pass all the dates between start date and end date for simple calendar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, calendar

i am using a booking system and i am using simple calendar gem ... i have a booking model which consist of start date and end date and the room ... now now if the customer selects to stay for 3 days and he select that same room i need to show in my simple calendar that he is staying from eg. 12-10-2016 13-10-2016 14-10-2016 and that particular room is selected.... but the problem here is it only shows the start date and the room booked for that day but it does not show the rest of the days rooms booked ...
how to i pass all the dates

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord


alias_attribute :start_time, :start_date

has_many :booking_rooms, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :booking
has_many :rooms, through: :booking_rooms
end

 class BookingRoom < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :room
    belongs_to :booking, inverse_of: :booking_rooms
 end

 class Room < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :booking_rooms
  has_many :bookings, through: :booking_rooms
end
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Please post the relevant model code.

Comment: thankx for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should do the trick for u

```
 class BookingRoom < ApplicationRecord
 def start_time
   self.booking.start_date.to_datetime
 end

 def end_time
   self.booking.end_date.to_datetime
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `start_time` alias:

```
alias_attribute :start_time, :start_date
```

You don't have `end_time` attribute, or alias, nor a setting for simple-calendar to override the default and so know what your end attribute is. Thus, simple-calendar thinks your `Booking` is a one-day event.

Comment: but how do i pass it to the simple calendar gem rails

Comment: thanks that was exactly wat ws missing....i tried doing that ...but now how  do i get in between dates to show too

Comment: That should be it. If you have `start_time` and `end_time` set up, simple-calendar should add each date in `start_time..end_time` to the calendar.